# Is it possible to use telegram bot inline button to get user live location?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to ask the user of the bot to share their live location using a message with two inline buttons (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton). One to share and the other to cancel. If the user click share, i want to receive his live location without him having to start sharing live location manually.

I have checked the apis and couldn't find anything. I only found one to send live location of the bot https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendlocation.

Is it possible to start receiving the user live location upon clicking the inline button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this answer: [How i can request the user's location in inline keyboard within telegram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68021560/how-i-can-request-the-users-location-in-inline-keyboard-within-telegram?rq=1) and [the official API docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots#location-and-number) - no, that isn't possible. Custom keyboard buttons can ask for the user's location, inline buttons can not.