# How i can request the user's location in inline keyboard within telegram?

Tags: location, telegram, telegraf

hi everyone I'm kinda new in telegram bot coding and I'm building a Geodata collector bot. I want to retrieve the location of the user in a button using the inline keyboard. there is just request_location param that can be used in the keyboard, not in the inline keyboard. I want also to use a callback for one of my buttons to gets back to the previous menu and I wasn't able to find a correct callback query for the keyboard. can sb help me that how I would be able to request the location in an inline keyboard?

//my buttons for acquiring the location

```
bot.action("POS-PCdF", (ctx) => {
  ctx.deleteMessage();
  console.log(ctx.from);
  bot.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, "Can we access your location?", {
    reply_markup: {
      keyboard: [
        [
          {
            text: "Access my location",
            request_location: true,
            callback_data: "Access_my_loc",
          },
          { text: "Cancel", callback_data: "PCdF" },
        ],
      ],
    },
  });
});
```

//the menu that I want to use in my callback

```
bot.action("PCdF", (ctx) => {
  ctx.deleteMessage();
  ctx.telegram.sendMessage(
    ctx.chat.id,
    "Share with us the problems about *******!",
    {
      reply_markup: {
        inline_keyboard: [
          [
            { text: "Pictures", callback_data: "PIC-PCdF" },
            { text: "Location", callback_data: "POS-PCdF" },
          ],
          [
            { text: "write to us", callback_data: "TEXT-PCdF" },
            { text: "Go back Home", callback_data: "go-back" },
          ],
        ],
      },
    }
  );
});
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [Official Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton), `InlineKeyboardMarkupButton` should contain exactly one of the following optional feilds: `callback_data`, `login_url`, `switch_inline_query`, `switch_inline_query_current_chat`, `callback_game`, `pay`

This means that an inline keyboard cannot have a button requesting for user's location AKA `request_location`.

Also, there's no built in button or solution for returning to the last keyboard (whether it's a `ReplyKeyboard` or a `InlineKeyboard`). You have to implement a return button with a proper `text` (`callback_data` if it's an `InlineKeyboardButton`) specifically declared so that your code can recognize it and return to the last keyboard.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. are there restrictions for writing the callback name for buttons? like, don't use some specific symbols?

Comment: The API doesn't limit any character usage but the data should not be any larger than 64 bytes.